# How to validate string using regex

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I want to validate an 8 character string with the following position-wise character constraints:

1. The **first** position must be one of these letters: `A/M/P/B/S`
2. **Second** and **third** position are letters from `AA` to `ZZ`
3. **Fourth** position contains a number between `1` - `4`
4. **Fifth** position contains a number between `1` - `4`
5. **Sixth - eighth** position must be a number `000` - `999`

If it doesn't match, it will return `FALSE`. Here is my code:

```
import re                       

text = input("input:")
print(text)
   check = re.search("[^S|B|M|P|A][AA-ZZ][1-4][1-4][000-999]", text)
if check: 
 print("TRUE")
else: 
 print("FALSE")
```

Ex : AIK22001
The Uotput should be 'True'

Here, I have tried using regex Python library, but the output was wrong. It returns `False` whether it is expected to be `True`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe try testing and fixing your regex on a [tool like this](https://regex101.com/) first and then implementing it in python. Dont forget to select python regex in the tool i linked.

Comment: Sorry but how can it ever actually print true. An 'if else if' statement will only run the 'elif' when the 'if' is false and 'elif' is true. If the 'if' is entered then the 'elif' and 'else' will not run. You define check in the 'if' statement so it is impossible therefore for the 'elif' to ever run. I believe this is just a typo error on your part and all you need to do is make the check a separate 'if' statement. or move it to before the 'if' statement

Comment: Somemthing like this? `^[AMPBS][A-Z]{2}[1-4]{2}\d{3}$`

Comment: `if len(text) == 8`, check is not defined. So it will fail. It will go in and execute re.search only if length of string is not equal to 8. You want to fix that first

Comment: your problem is if statement not regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use the regex101 site that Akshay Sehgal mentioned above:

https://regex101.com/r/KtzJY6/1

You'll see the regex there is `^[AMPBS][A-Z]{2}[1-4]{2}[0-9]{3}$`.  Important features to note here:

- The anchors `^` and `$` attach to the beginning and ending of the string, which prevents inputs that are too short and too long from matching.
- Quantifiers like `{2}`, which means "two of the previous things"
- Notice how square brackets `[]` work.  You don't need `|` in the middle of them, and ranges only work on single characters; `[AA-ZZ]` matches 'A', anything between 'A' and 'Z', and 'Z', which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I think you missed a `[1-4]`

Comment: thanks a lot, this is very useful, it clears my problem